# How can I split a string to get a sentence between a certain character and an uncertain character

Tags: java, string, split

`String myString = "OID.1.2.840.113549.1.9.2=Responsable: Fernando Martínez Coss, L=Cuauhtemoc, ST=Distrito Federal, C=MX, OID.2.5.4.17=06300, STREET="Av. Hidalgo 77, Col. Guerrero", EMAILADDRESS=acods@sat.gob.mx, O=Servicio de Administración Tributaria, CN=A.C. del Servicio de Administración Tributaria";`

I have that one, excuse the spanish. How can I get all the characters after the "CN=" The CN propertie might not fall always at the end of the string, and could have any character after it.

It this particular case the CN= falls conveniently at the end of the string, but it is possible that it might end with a comma, or another character that it is not a letter or number.

Like:

```
CN=A.C. del Servicio de Administración Tributaria/email
CN=A.C. del Servicio de Administración Tributaria,  Somethings.
```

I just want specifically the value before the slash and the comma and after the equals.

Comment: It looks like most of the pieces are terminated with ",".  Can't you rely on that?

Comment: What do you want to get, if the CN isn't the last entry? `all the characters after the "CN="`? Or just that value of the key/value pair?

Comment: I updated my answer to detect `/` and `,`. Your description `another character that it is not a letter or number` is still not completly accurate, since we see a dot (A.C.) and, of course, blanks. What about tabs? Apostrophs (think: `O'Reilly`).

Comment: I think it'll be fine with those.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could assume that the "CN" element will always be either at the end of the string or followed by another "X=Y" sequence, so perhaps you could try this:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("CN=(.*?)($|, [A-Z]+)=.*");
Matcher m = p.matcher(myString);
if (m.find()) {
  // Now m.group(1) contains the value associated with "CN".
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
String myString = "OID.1.2.840.113549.1.9.2=Responsable: Fernando Martínez Coss, L=Cuauhtemoc, ST=Distrito Federal, C=MX, OID.2.5.4.17=06300, STREET="Av. Hidalgo 77, Col. Guerrero", EMAILADDRESS=acods@sat.gob.mx, O=Servicio de Administración Tributaria, CN=A.C. del Servicio de Administración Tributaria";

int indexCn = myString.indexOf("CN");
int indexComma = myString(",", indexCn );
return indexComma == -1 ? myString.substring( indexCn ) : myString.substring( indexCn, indexComma - indexCn );
```

You need to handle two cases

1. CN is the last element (so no comma afterwards, just end of String)
2. CN is in the middle, so we have a comma as a delimiter.

Comment: `myString.indexOf` with lowercase i, next line: missing `indexOf`, `substring` with two lowercase s (2x). Did you see the "," in the value `STREET="Av. Hidalgo 77, Col. Guerrero"`? I doubt a bit.

Comment: Yeah I haven't done Java in a while. Regarding the commas inside the string, I noticed them but ignored them as the CN (as per the question) didn't contain any.

Answer (score 1):

```
String myString = "OID.1.2.840.113549.1.9.2=Responsable: Fernando Martínez Coss, L=Cuauhtemoc, ST=Distrito Federal, C=MX, OID.2.5.4.17=06300, STREET=\"Av. Hidalgo 77, Col. Guerrero\", EMAILADDRESS=acods@sat.gob.mx, O=Servicio de Administración Tributaria, CN=A.C. del Servicio de Administración Tributaria";

Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("CN=([^,]*)");

Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(myString);

if(matcher.find())
{
    System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this without regexp in this way - especially this can be good if you will want retrieve more parameters

**Example 1**

```
String myString = ...;
String[] firstSplit = myString.split(",");
for (int i=0; i<firstSplit.length; i++) {
    String[] secondSplit = firstSplit[i].split("=");
    if ("CN".equals(secondSplit[0].trim())) {
        System.out.println(secondSplit[1]);
    }
}
```

But this will only work if you will use "," only to separate parameters. If you can't treat "," like delimiter then the best way will be regexp or indexof method

Comment: I'm afraid I don't have specific delimiters for this one, if Ihad I could probably had found the answer elsewhere already.

Answer (score 1):

For the updated question:

```
result = myS.replaceAll (".*CN=", "").replaceAll ("[,/].*", "");
result = result.replaceAll ("[A-Z0-9.]+=", "");
```

(updated again, to include `[,/]` from the updated question). 
(updated again, in reaction to newest comment)

Comment: What if there are no commas or slashes, but a space following another "XY=" statement? Sorry about that, most update question. It just occured to me It's possible this might happen.

Comment: so the statement may end in: 1. End of String, 2. Comma (no comma in the CN-String possible?), 3. Slash, 4. UPPERCASE= (the next entry). And a new entry always begins with just uppercase letters, followed by a equal sign, immediately? Oh, no, I see, OID contains numbers and dots too. Something else we should know? ;)